# Can we use Node.js in Marketing Cloudpages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, cloudpage, python, node.js

We are planning to make Web scrapping tool in cloud pages using node.js . I want to know can we use node.js libraries and function in cloudpages ?

We have a Url of a web page as input .`Request {Url}`
We will fetch the HTML source code of this page. `Fetch{Html source code}`
do some operation to get its data `Extract {Html Tag data}.`
display it on Cloud pages in Tabular format.

Please let me know if we can use node.js combined with HTML to achieve this task in cloud page ? or any other technologies(python ..etc) which can be used within CloudPages

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't run Node.js in a CloudPage. On the server side, you're limited to using SFMC's implementation of [Server Side JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.htm) (SSJS) or [AMPScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm). Both languages have features to support your use case, including making HTTP requests to syndicate content. AMPScript has better [support for processing XML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rssFeedEmail.htm) based content and SSJS includes native support for parsing JSON based content using the Platform Library's [Content Syndication Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationFunctions.htm).